# How to escape a percent sign in "EXECUTE format('blah')"

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have two tables, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1
(
    one_column   INTEGER,
    two_column   INTEGER,
    three_column INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE table_2
(
    id        SERIAL,
    column_1  INTEGER,
    column_2  INTEGER,
    column_3  INTEGER,
    name      TEXT,
    step      INTEGER
);
```

I also have a stored function which receives a number of parameters. Within the function, I `INSERT` a row into a table using a call to `EXECUTE format()`, something like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE function_p (
    p_name TEXT DEFAULT '',
    p_step INT DEFAULT NULL
    )
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('
    INSERT INTO table_2 (column_1,column_2,column_3,name,step)
    SELECT one_column, two_column,three_column,%L,%s
    FROM table_1',p_name,p_step);   
END;
$$
```

(Thanks to @jim-jones)

However, in my 'actual' function, I also have an `INNER JOIN` in the `SELECT` which has something like the following condition...

```
    ON (month_diff(d, now()::DATE) % month_interval) = 0
```

I'm getting an error like **unrecognized format() type specifier " "** and I'm thinking do I need to escape the '`%`' sign and, if so, how? is it '`\%`' or '`%%`' or something else? I've tried these and get the same failure.

Comment: `%%` should work: what you get here? `SELECT FORMAT('%s%%',1)`

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-format/): If you want to include % in the result string, use double percentages %%. Since you already tried that perhaps you could try `\%%` or even `%%%`.

Comment: You want to calculate a modulo ?

Comment: Sorry, I tried `%%` and didn't notice it was working as another error in my nonsense code came up. Stupid deadlines and tired developer here... Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem has to be somewhere else. `%%` does the trick:

```
SELECT
  format('%s%%',42),
  format('%1s%%',42),
  format('%2$s%% - %1$s%%',42,73); -- $ index for customized order

 format | format |  format   
--------+--------+-----------
 42%    | 42%    | 73% - 42%
(1 row)
```

This is mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT):

> In addition to the format specifiers described above, the special sequence `%%` may be used to output a literal `%` character.